# I don't know how to call using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation in a C# script inside my own Package in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't know how to call using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation in a C# script inside my own Package in Unity.
I have added ARFoundation in Dependencies of Package as shown in the image. But I'm getting "error CS0246: The type or namespace name '~' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". How can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating Assembly Difinition Files in my own package and adding references to Assembly Difinition References.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue in "Edit" ... "Preferences" ... "External Tools", by checking "Regenerate Project Files"; this hopefully regenerates all the necessary ".csproj" files for IntelliSense tracking.